# Flatmap Promise in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

This must have been asked before, but how do you flatten a promise in JS?

Something like this:

```
let justAPromise: Promise<something> = aPromise.flatMap( a => getAnotherPromise());
```

Or something like this:

```
let promiseOfPromise: Promise<Promise<something>> = aPromise.then( a => getAnotherPromise());
let justAPromise: Promise<something> = promiseOfPromise.flatten();
```

EDIT:

Clarification on what I mean by flattening a promise. I see a massive difference between the following two. The first is a promise of int, and the second is a promise of a promise of int:

```
Promise.resolve(23);

Promise.resolve("whatever").then(a => Promise.resolve(23));
```

Comment: You can't flatten Promises, you can only flatten arrays, I'm not sure precisely what you're asking for..?

Comment: The .then() is actually the .flatmap() on the Promise with some extra stuff, like it wraps the returned value into Promise automatically when it wasn't, catches and wraps exception and etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just chain your promises:

```
let justAPromise: Promise<something> = aPromise.then( a => getAnotherPromise());
```

The example below show you that it's flattend by this way:

```js
var aPromise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("a"), 1000));
var getAnotherPromise = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve("another"), 1000));
var justAPromise = aPromise.then(a => getAnotherPromise());
justAPromise.then(res => console.log(res)); // <-- this print "another"
```

Comment: But this is now a `Promise<Promise<something>>>`

Comment: No, it's not a Promise<Promise<something>>. `justPromise` is now  the return value of  `getAnotherPromise`

Comment: hmm... So does JS flatten promises magically itself? Cause `aPromise.then(a => 23)` is not the same as `aPromise.then(a => Promise.resolve(23))`

Comment: It doesn't matter either you return `something` or promise of `something` in the then callback. It's always flatten either

Comment: yes, `.then()` works differently if you return another `Promise` or value of any other type.

Comment: K, thanks, another bit of unexpected JS magic :) other languages don't just flatten it for you.

Comment: @eddyP23 Check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then it says `If it (the parameter you pass) is not a function, it is internally replaced with an "Identity" function (it returns the received argument)`. So if you pass a Promise (or anything other than a function), it will just return itself (in this case, a Promise)